# Please interpret and analyze sentences

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics, figurative-language

i have a one simple question.

This is the lyric from the movie 'tangled'.

"All those years **outside looking in**"

I'd like to know more about this phrase. "outside looking in"

1. Does that mean you're looking inside from the outside or just looking outside?
2. Is it "outside" an adj?

Comment: Yes, you are outside a place and looking into that place (the place could be metaphorical). I think 'outside' is a preposition here.

Answer (score -1):

let me divide them for you:
all these years / outside / looking in.
**Outside:** meaning when i was outside.
**looking in:** when i was looking in.